# How to replace http with https via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following rss object on my page...

```
data.data[i].link
```

and it produces the following URL...

```
http://
```

I would like the URL instead to start out with...

```
https://
```

What would be the easiest way to modify this?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
data.data[i].link.replace('http://','https://');
```